# How to set up imports in a Python Monorepo for microservices?

Tags: python, microservices, python-packaging, monorepo, pyproject.toml

[architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X6s4.png)

I try to set up this kind of monorepo. However, pyproject.toml doesn't allow relative imports. How can I still use utils in the API-projects?

I tried relative imports in the pyproject.toml of an API, but pyproject.toml doesn't allow it

Answer (score -2):

Do not use a monorepo for microservices.

The goal of microservices is to be able to release a new version of ONE microservice without having to rebuild / retest / release all the code base.